# How to animate a func comp in react?

Tags: css, reactjs

I normally, in a class based comp just use componentDidMount and setTimeout to set the state and dynamically and add a class to the main div and animate that. I am sort of trying to do the same thing just pass the class to the func comp, but it's not working. I would like to stick to using pure css for now.

I have a functional component in React like so:

```
import React from 'react';

export default (props.class) => {
 return (
  <div className={`animate ${props.class}`}>
    Hello World
  </div>
 )
}
```

---

```
Main App:
```

---

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import FuncComp from './FuncComp';

export default class App extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props) 

  this.state = { class: '' }
 }

 componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => { this.setState({class: 'animateAction'}), 0)
 }

 render(){
  return (
  <div>
   <FuncComp class={this.state.class} />
  </div>
 )
}
}
```

External CSS:

```
.animate {
 transform: scaleY(0);
 transition: transform 1s ease;
}
.animateAction {
 transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm doing this from my phone, everything is correct in my code, but I may have typos on here. sorry about that. But that is a prop, not a className

Comment: you can use https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be a bit of a confusing answer I suppose, but I found a way to animate on load and a way to delay the unmounting of a Component as well.

This is for functional components as half of this you can do in a class based comp in the comp itself.

EDIT: this does work for class based comp as well from what I have found.

Note: base is the base class, and action is the action you want to happen for the animation.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default Comp => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        shouldRender: this.props.isMounted,
        didMount: false
      }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      if (this.props.isMounted && !nextProps.isMounted) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({ shouldRender: false })
        }, this.props.delayTime)
        this.setState({ didMount: false })
      } else if (!this.props.isMounted && nextProps.isMounted) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({ didMount: true })
        }, 0)
        this.setState({ shouldRender: true })
      }
    }

    render() {
      const { didMount } = this.state
      const { base, action, isMounted } = this.props
      return this.state.shouldRender ? (
        <div className={`${base} ${didMount && isMounted ? action : ''}`}>
          <Comp {...this.props} />
        </div>
      ) : null
    }
  }
}
```

Okay now using this new HOC we can wrap our func comp like so.

```
import React from 'react'
import AnimateHOC from './AnimateHOC'

const myFuncComp = (props.class) => {
 return (
  <h1>
    Hello World
  </h1>
 )
}

const AnimateComp = AnimateHOC(myFuncComp);
```

Inside a class based comp use like so:

```
render() {
 return (
  <div>
   <AnimateComp
    delayTime={500}
    isMounted={this.state.isMounted}
    base={'animate'}
    action={'animateAction'}
   />
   <button onClick={this.setState({ isMounted: !this.state.isMounted }) }>Toggle</button>
  </div>
 )
}
```

and then finally your external css:

```
 .animate {
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: top;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
  }

  .animateAction {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
```

**CRITICAL** : match the delay time to your animate time, otherwise this will not work correctly. Delay time is in MS so 500 = .5s